# Using regex match.map to insert React <img> into existing string

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs

Based on one of my previous questions, I know how to take a string and replace it entirely with React image elements.

```js
if (source.match(/\{([0-z,½,∞]+)\}/g)) {
      tagged = source.match(/\{([0-z,½,∞]+)\}/g)
      .map(function (basename, i) {
          var src = './src/img/' + basename.substring(1, basename.length - 1).toLowerCase() + '.png';
          return <img key={i} src={src} height='15px'/>;
      });
    }
```

The above works great. However, now I have the need to take a string and replace only parts of it with image elements (which the above code doesn't do; it doesn't save any surrounding text). So what I tried was:

```js
tagged = source.replace(/\{([0-z,½,∞]+)\}/g, function(basename) {
      var src = './src/img/' + basename.substring(1, basename.length - 1).toLowerCase() + '.png';
      return <img src={src} height='15px'/>});
```

(which is shown in http://regexr.com/3cq7n, except I can't add a function to the replace part). The problem is, `tagged` is a string of objects, rather than being actual objects like what the first `.map` code returned. However, it successfully embedded the objects within the text rather than destroying the surrounding text. How do I combine the two, so I'm embedding proper `<img>` elements in the text?

edit: tried this double-replace regex but it doesn't work either...

```js
tagged = <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: ent.encode(source).replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br/>').replace(/\{([0-z,½,∞]+)\}/g, (fullMatch, firstMatch) =>
        `<img src=./src/img/${firstMatch.toLowerCase()}.png height=12px/>`
      )}}></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, React.js doesn't automatically convert nodes to their HTML representation. You can create the `<img>`s as strings, though, like this:

```
tagged = source.replace(/\{([0-z,½,∞]+)\}/g, (fullMatch, firstMatch) =>
    `<img src=./src/img/${firstMatch.toLowerCase()}.png height=15px />`
);
```

If you need to return it from a component, you will need to wrap it in a `<div>` or other element, like this:

```
return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: source.replace(/\{([0-z,½,∞]+)\}/g, (fullMatch, firstMatch) =>
    `<img src=./src/img/${firstMatch.toLowerCase()}.png height=15px />`
)}}></div>
```

React.js will set the `innerHTML` to the string which is created.

**Please note that both of these could create an XSS vulnerability!** `source` could potentially contain `<script>`s or other HTML elements. If you wish to work around this, you could run `source` through an HTML encoder *before* replacing the tags in it (i.e. `tagged = htmlEncode(source).replace(…)`).

Comment: OK, that works really well. Two questions; I tried to do ```{{__html: htmlEncode(source).replace ... }}``` but it didn't find htmlEncode; is that a standard function or do I have to create it?
I realised there are newlines in the original source text, and they aren't being shown in the output. I was using nl2br before, but that only works on text. Is there any way to do that on a created component?

Comment: @IronWaffleMan Yes, you need to create a function called `htmlEncode`. Use `nl2br` like this: `nl2br(htmlEncode(source)).replace(…)`

Comment: @IronWaffleMan Otherwise, do a simple replace, like this: `htmlEncode(source).replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br/>).replace(…)`

Comment: Neither of those work... I have [nl2br](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-nl2br) and a [html encoder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ent) and I tried both your suggestions. The first one says ```TypeError: nl2br(...).replace is not a function```. The second one just returns the same as without the first replace (I assume you meant ```<br/>``` instead of ```'<br.>``` because that returns a syntax error with an unclosed quote?).

Comment: @IronWaffleMan Apparently `nl2br` converts newlines to React.js `<br/>` elements. That means the image tagging replace won't work. I meant `htmlEncode(source).replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br/>').replace(…)`. That should work properly.

Comment: Tried that too, also didn't work. What I end up with is an object with a ```props.dangerouslySetInnerHtml.__html``` property which contains the text. The ```<img>``` tags in it show up fine, but the ```<br/>``` have become ```&#10;``` instead. I tried encoding/decoding with ent after the double replace but that requires a string so that didn't work either (neither did using ```.toString()``` and then encoding/decoding).

Comment: @IronWaffleMan For some reason, your HTML encoder is converting newlines to `&#10;`. Use `/&#10;/g` as the regular expression.

Comment: Ah, perfect, that did the trick! I'm assuming now that I'm encoding the html, even though I'm setting it dangerously, it should be relatively safe and it's not creating an XSS vulnerability?

Comment: @IronWaffleMan Yes, that is correct. There is not any XSS vunerability in that method.